# How can I stop the optimization process of scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b manually?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using `spicy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b` for optimization.

The calculator for calculating the `loss` and `grad` is realized by a class

```
from calculator import loss_calculator

class one_batch:

    def __init__(self, setup_dict):
        self.setup_dict = setup_dict 

    def calculate(self):
        temp_instance = loss_calculator(self.setup_dict, self.parameters)
        self.loss, self.grad = temp_instance.result()

    def objective_function(self, parameter):
        self.parameters = parameters 
        self.calculate()
        ###########################################################
        #  I want to check if some convergence occures here. If   #
        #   the convergence occurs, stop l-bfgs-b optimization.   #
        ###########################################################
        return self.loss, self.grad
```

For optimization, an instance of `one_batch` will be created every time a new batch of examples is loaded.

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_l_bfgs_b as optimizer
model_vector = initial_vector
for n in range(niter):
    setup_dict = setup_dict # load the batch of examples 
    temp_batch = one_batch(setup_dict)
    model_update = optimizer(temp_batch.objective_function, x0=model_vector)
    model_vector = model_update
```

As you can see from the code, what I want to achieve is:

When `optimizer` calls `temp_batch.objective_function` for minimizing the loss function, if some convergence occurs, I want to 'break' the optimization process coded in `spicy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title. It's got flavor  :)

Comment: @Mad Physicist Sorry, English is not my native language...

Comment: I don't think spelling scipy as spicy qualifies as an English issue per se. :)

Comment: @Mad Physicist sorry, I didn't notice that :)

Comment: Where is any of this code actually called? Could you show a minimal working example that doesn't terminate early but otherwise works?

Comment: @Mad Physicist I have added the part that calls `one_batch`, the only ways I know that terminate the optimization process are `maxfun` and `maxiter `, but it seems they are not related to convergence check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convergence related parameters for l_bfgs_b algo are

1. `factr` - Default value is 1e7, increase its value if you want to early stop the fitting.

Typical values for factr are: 1e12 for low accuracy; 1e7 for moderate accuracy; 10.0 for extremely high accuracy.

If you are familiar with optimize.minimize function, then relationship between `ftol` and `factr` is given in [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html).

> Note that the ftol option is made available via that interface, while
>   factr is provided via this interface, where factr is the factor
>   multiplying the default machine floating-point precision to arrive at
>   ftol: ftol = factr * numpy.finfo(float).eps.

2. `pgtol` : float, optional

> The iteration will stop when max{|proj g_i | i = 1, ..., n} <= pgtol
>   where pg_i is the i-th component of the projected gradient.

Try [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html#optimize-minimize-lbfgsb), if your want to do **optimize.minimize** method using `l_bfgs_b`